# WPF DataGrid - add button to end of every row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'd like to add a button to the end of every row of my datagrid. I've found the following xaml but it adds the button to the start. Anyone know how I can add it after all the databound columns?

This adds the button to the start instead of the end:

```
  <DataGrid Background ="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding PriceList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button>My button</Button>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: How this binding works?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to add the columns manually.

Turn off the autogeneration of the columns and add them in the order you want them, including your extra column at the end of the list:

```
  <DataGrid Background ="Black"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PriceList}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

      <!-- Add your normal columns here -->

      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button>My button</Button>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the button control with some styles. The Style defines a Trigger element that changes the background property and visibility of a button based on button content/text.

```html
 <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dgvProcessLists" SelectionMode="Single">\
<DataGrid.Columns><DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SIZE_FP}" FontFamily="Verdana" Header="SIZE FP" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="140" Header="Command">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="{Binding  DB_STEP_NAME}" Tag="{Binding STEP_ORDER}" Click="btnContinue_Click" >
                                        <Button.Style>
                                            <Style x:Name="ButtonVisibility">
                                                <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="Failed">
                                                        <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#777777"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="Execute">
                                                        <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="Re-Evaluate">
                                                        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>                                                    
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Value="Final">
                                                        <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Style>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
</Datagrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DataGrid looks like this try following example:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PriceList}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                           <Button>My button</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which column by its name with a converter!

I created my columns like this: (maybe it works with another method)

```
DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
column.Binding = new Binding("ColumnName");
dataGrid.Columns.Add(column)
```

In your `DataTrigger` you define a different `DataTemplate` when the column has a certain name:

```
...
xmlns:tools="clr-namespace:App.Tools"
...

<ResourceDictionary>

    <tools:CustomButtonConverter x:Key="CustomButtonConv" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomButton">
        <Button Click="HandlerClick" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource CustomButtonConv}}" Value="ColumnName">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CustomButton}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>

...

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" />
```

Replace `ColumnName` by the name of your column...

Your converter:

```
namespace App.Tools
{
    public class CustomButtonConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var dataGridTextColumn = value as DataGridTextColumn;
            return dataGridTextColumn.SortMemberPath;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```