# Adding dynamic button on each row in datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have below `DataGrid` in my `xaml` page:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataCDetails" AlternationCount="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,233,10,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="482" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" MouseLeftButtonDown="DataCDetails_MouseLeftButtonDown" Width="937">
```

and in the code behind am fetching few `json` data and adding it as `datagrid` columns as below:

```
// Response converted to JSON
DataResponse dataResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataResponse>(response);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Dictionary<string, string> cols = new Dictionary<string, string>();

cols.Add("Column 1", "Col1");
cols.Add("Column 2", "Col2");
cols.Add("Column 3", "Col3");
cols.Add("Column 4", "Col4");
cols.Add("Column 5", "Col5");
cols.Add("Actions", "Actions");

foreach (var col in cols)
{
       var column = new DataGridTextColumn
       {
             Header = col.Key,
             Binding = new Binding(col.Value)
       };
       DataCDetails.Columns.Add(column);
}
foreach (var item in dataResponse.entry_list)
{
           var col1 = item.col1;
           var col2 = item.col2;
           var col3 = item.col3;
           var col4 = item.col4;
           var col5 = item.col5;
           DataCDetails.Items.Add(new ColumnItems { Col1 = col1, Col2 = col2, Col3 = col3, Col4 = col4, Col5 = col5});
}
```

My `ColumnItems` class is as below:

```
public class ColumnItems
{
     public string Col1 { get; set; }
     public string Col2 { get; set; }
     public string Col3 { get; set; }
     public string Col4 { get; set; }
     public string Col5 { get; set; }
}
```

Now how I can add a dynamic `button` as last column to each row in DataGrid? I've tried to add `Button` data property to my `ColumnItems` class, and then tried to add it as `Action = new Button()` inside `DataCDetails.Items.Add` but it did not work well. Hope somebody will provide knowledge to me on this.

Comment: given that `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to `"False"`, you have columns declaration in xaml, I guess. In that case use `DataGridTemplateColumn`. check example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476423/wpf-datagrid-add-button-to-end-of-every-row

Comment: Agreed @ASh somehow following the same way...

Comment: Any help on this? I am searching for the same solution, but my COLUMNS are even dynamic, i.e created from the code itself. I need to add extra column and want a button in each row generated,